# Can you update disc-based games on the Xbox360?

Tags: xbox-360

Can you update the games that are distributed by the publisher on discs (*i.e.* not downloaded content)?

If you can update them, how do you do so?

Comment: Are you looking to buy an xbox 360 or? This can be tested quite easily.

Answer (score 7):

If a game needs updates, they will be downloaded if you are connected to the Internet. You can not update the data on the disc, so when you use the disc in a console that hasn't downloaded the updates yet, you will need to download them again even if you've downloaded updates while launching the game with that same disc on another console.

Comment: Also keep in mind that a lot of updates delete updates from other games (just patches, not dlc), a friend of me and me liked playing gears of war on 1.0 together, so we inserted a viva pinata disc before starting gears and then disconnected the console to be able to play on gears 1.0 :)